# How to redirect properly in RESTful Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I'm trying to send PUT request to the handler of my controller all works fine

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT,
                consumes = "application/json",
                headers = "content-type=application/json")
public String updateCompany(@RequestBody Company company) {
    companyRepository.updateCompany(company);
    return "redirect:/api/company/" + company.getId();
}
```

But when it redirect to another handler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = GET,
                produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Company getCompany(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    Company c = companyRepository.getCompany(id);
    return new CompanyToJsonWrapper(c);
}
```

I'm getting `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported` error. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You are missing the code which actually CALLS the webservice. The problem is likely there. I suspect the client is sending a PUT request to a webservice which expects a GET request.

Comment: Yes, that's right. So I can't change some header to do redirect with GET?

Comment: I think this task is impossible to solve :(

Comment: You are not doing redirecting or want to do any redirecting, you simply want to call a webservice using the proper request method. Until you share the code of the client, there is little anyone can do to assist you there.

Comment: Are you sure that the PUT method invoked probably "can you add logging lines in the method to be sure", as once you are using redirect it will be GET method, What I think about that your PUT call with incorrect URI so it is giving this error.

Comment: I know that this is old now, but you were doing the right thing. You should always redirect after a put, and it isn't very difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to do this. It doesn't make sense. Why would you want to PUT new information and then redirect to a GET? What's you intent, to return the Company once it has been updated? If so then why not just return the Company from your PUT? Else, have your client make a second REST call to the GET instead of redirecting from your Controller.

Comment: It makes lots of sense to do this. For example, after the redirect the user can hit refresh without redoing their put request. In fact, this put and redirect is the only correct way to deal with a put in a rest service. The put creates a resource, how is the client meant to know which resource to request if it isn't redirected? If the resource is returned directly from the put, how does its id get into the uri?